# Group similar notifications in Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, notifications, laravel-5, eloquent

My notifications table looks like the following

```
id (eg. 1) | from_id (eg. 1) | from_type (eg. liked) | to_id (eg. 2) | to_type (comment) | item_id (eg. 1) | read (0 or 1) | created_at | updated_at
```

Currently when I fetch notifications in Laravel, I make this call

```
$notifs = Notification::with('from')
                        ->where("to_id", "=", $user_id)
                        ->where("read", "=", 0)
                        ->limit(40)
                        ->get();
```

This works perfectly, except I've decided to move on to grouping the notifications by type so that the user can get "13 people have liked you post" as opposed to 13 separate notifications saying that their post has been liked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just grouping by one dimension, you can use [`groupBy()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-groupby) on the resulting collection, e.g.:

```
$grouped_notifs = $notifs->groupBy('from_type');
```

This will give you a collection of arrays. You can then loop through and output aggregate data for arrays that have a count > 1.

It sounds like you probably want to group by both `from_type` and `to_type` though. To accomplish that you could add one more layer by turning each array from `$grouped_notifs` into a collection and running the `groupBy()` filter there as well.

```
foreach( $grouped_notifs as $from_type_group ) {
    if( count($from_type_group) === 1 ) {
        // just output $from_type_group[0] since there's just one
    }
    else {
        // This group has more than one item
        $to_type_groups = collect($from_type_group)->groupBy('to_type');

        foreach( $to_type_groups as $to_type_group ) {
            if( count($to_type_group) === 1 ) {
                // output $to_type_group[0]
            }
            else {
                // Output aggregate based on from_type, to_type, and count()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Performance-wise, it might be better to craft a DB query that groups everything appropriately, but if you want to keep it in Eloquent then this should work.